# c++ - mysql connector keep connection open

Tags: c++, mysql, memory-leaks

I'm bulding a rest api in c++ and my program are always running in cloud. I'm using the mysql connector for c++ to communicate with mysql database.

For example, to establish a connection:

```
sql::mysql::MySQL_Driver *driver;
sql::Connection *con;

driver = sql::mysql::get_mysql_driver_instance();
con = driver->connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:3306", "user", "password");

delete con;
```

If you see when i dont need more the `con` object i need to delete it and free the memory (" Make sure that you free con, the sql::Connection object, as soon as you do not need it any more. "  by -> https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-cpp/en/connector-cpp-examples-connecting.html). But in my case i think that no make sense for each request create a new `con`.

If it is a `rest api` and they are always running in real time i think that is more elegant to create a single connection and in each request i use that connection. For example if i have 10 requests to the same thing (user info) it is not elegant to create and delete 10 connections...

I try this solution (create one single connection when i run the program in first time and use always the same connection), its works but in future it would originate memory leaks because i never free memory to the `con` and others objects that its always necessary to use in each request to database. And i cannot free the `con` object in this case because in some next request i get `segmentation fault` because i already `delete` and `free` the `con` object and dont create anymore because i only create the connection in first program running and i kept that connection always open.

So there are some way to always keep the connection open without having in future problems with memory leak?

Comment: C != C++. Tag with only one of them.

Comment: I already fix the tag. It was inadvertently

Comment: And related to the question, you know some other way? :)

Comment: You may want to post to the MySQL forums.

Comment: I am looking for the same solution, seems nobody can answer....